# Obtener el Height de mi container con javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

Tengo un codigo de javascript que me muestra un scroll dentro de un div, pero el scroll no obtiene el total de la pagina, en este caso el height y le estoy asignando un height desde css por ahora

```
$(document).ready(function () { //Cuando el Doc. se cargue totalmente.

// The bugged way 
$('.linked-scrollbar').scroll(function() {
$('.linked-scrollbar').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
})

// Fix of the slow scrolling 
$('.linked-scrollbar-fixed').attr("data-scrolling", "false");

$('.linked-scrollbar-fixed').scroll(function() {
if ($(this).attr("data-scrolling") == "false") {
  $('.linked-scrollbar-fixed').not(this).attr("data-scrolling", "true");
  $('.linked-scrollbar-fixed').not(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
}
$(this).attr("data-scrolling", "false");
});
});
```

Pero necesito pasar el valor del total de la pagina para que el scroll se deslice de manera completa y no se queda a la mitad en caso de que el height sea chico

tengo esto en mi css

```
.force-overflow {
min-height: 3700px; 
/* debe asignarce con js para tu scrollbar , del mismo tamano que tu container */
height: auto;
/* width: 90%; */
}
```

Sinceramente no tengo ocupo mucho JS, alguna idea?
Gracias.

Comment: has probado con obj.scrollHeight para obtener la altura?

Comment: Tambien prueba `element.clientHeight` mas info [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)